# Issue calling objectAtIndex method to get random color

Tags: objective-c, arc4random

Beginner to objective-c, so please excuse basic mistakes.

Goal is to set `predictionLabel.textColor` to a random color from an array.

```
// fill array colors
self.colors = @[@"redColor", @"greenColor", @"blueColor", @"greyColor", @"orangeColor", @"purpleColor"];

// get random number based on array count
int randomColor = arc4random_uniform(self.colors.count);

// set predictionLabel.textColor to random color
self.predictionLabel.textColor = [UIColor [self.colors objectAtIndex:randomColor]];
```

I keep getting the error message "Expected identifier" at `[UIColor [self.colors`.

Being new, I'm having a hard time troubleshooting this one. Any advice?

Comment: The result of a method cannot be used as a compile time constant.

Comment: I think you had something like this in mind... `self.predictionLabel.textColor = [[UIColor class] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(randomColor)];` This is terrifying code. Use Aaron's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using Key Value Coding, though you want to. You're really just guessing about the method names that might be on `UIColor`. Why not use an array of `UIColor` objects instead of the names of the class methods. Like this:

```
self.colors = @[[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor], [UIColor grayColor], UIColor orangeColor], [UIColor purpleColor]];

// get random number based on array count
int randomColor = arc4random_uniform(self.colors.count);

// set predictionLabel.textColor to random color
self.predictionLabel.textColor = [self.colors objectAtIndex:randomColor];
```

Also, watch the spelling of "grey" vs "gray". `[UIColor greyColor]` doesn't exist.

Comment: If you want to use the text based method for calling for values of a certain key on a class, use @moby's answer. He's got what you want.

Comment: This solution is far superior because you can put any color in the array. Using string representations of the built-in `UIColor` objects is very limiting.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is like doing:

```
[UIColor @"redColor"];
```

which just won't compile and is not valid syntax.

If you insist on using strings, you could do:

```
self.predictionLabel.textColor = [UIColor valueForKey:[self.colors objectAtIndex:randomColor]];
```

Comment: More importantly the result is only known at runtime.